Advantages of Euler vs Quaternion vs Axis-Angle Paramertization
I have spent a bit of time studying attitude estimation and I noticed that uncertainty of orientation can basically be represented in three forms.
Euler angles, Axis Angle and Quaternions. Quaternions are over-paramertized so you often expand them about the identity quaternion and use MKF, the same technique can also be used for euler angles and axis-angle.
In a lot of systems it appears the axis-angle form of uncertainty is used.
What are the benefits/drawbacks of each?
